# How to save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml or *.msg file

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailmessage, eml

How do I save MailMessage object to the disk? The MailMessage object does not expose any Save() methods.

I dont have a problem if it saves in any format, *.eml or *.msg. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll just quote an explanation from a [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94725):

> You can actually configure the
>   SmtpClient to send emails to the file
>   system instead of the network. You can
>   do this programmatically using the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtphost");
> client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
> client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\somedirectory";
> client.Send(message);
> ```
>
> You can also set this up in your
>   application configuration file like
>   this:

```
 <configuration>
     <system.net>
         <mailSettings>
             <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                 <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\somedirectory" />
             </smtp>
         </mailSettings>
     </system.net>
 </configuration>
```

> After sending the email, you should
>   see email files get added to the
>   directory you specified. You can then
>   have a separate process send out the
>   email messages in batch mode.

You should be able to use the empty constructor instead of the one listed, as it won't be sending it anyway.

Comment: I've found that I also needed to add the <network host="...", etc. in addition to what Ryan provided.

Comment: Is there any way to change the file name of the output .eml file? I would prefer it not to look like the following: f80f4695-551c-47d7-8879-40ad89707b23.eml Thanks!

Comment: Although an old post, I would like to add an answer to the last question from @buzzzzjay: have a look here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma)

Comment: good, it works for me. Further how can I open Outlook to open just saved file on client side.

Comment: @qazifarhan refer to my answer if you need access to the EML file in your code.

Comment: I there anyway to set the file names that get saved?

Comment: Don't forget to  message.Headers.Add("X-Unsent", "1"); this way you'll have the send option when it is opened.

Answer (score 31):

Here's an extension method to convert a MailMessage to a stream containing the EML data.
Its obviously a bit of a hack as it uses the file system, but it works.

```
public static void SaveMailMessage(this MailMessage msg, string filePath)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        msg.ToEMLStream(fs);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts a MailMessage to an EML file stream.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="msg"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static void ToEMLStream(this MailMessage msg, Stream str)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var tempFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

        tempFolder = Path.Combine(tempFolder, "MailMessageToEMLTemp");

        // create a temp folder to hold just this .eml file so that we can find it easily.
        tempFolder = Path.Combine(tempFolder, id.ToString());

        if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
        }

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
        client.PickupDirectoryLocation = tempFolder;
        client.Send(msg);

        // tempFolder should contain 1 eml file

        var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(tempFolder).Single();

        // stream out the contents
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(str);
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
        {
            Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then take the stream thats returned and do as you want with it, including saving to another location on disk or storing in a database field, or even emailing as an attachment.

Comment: Hi Saille... Your code works well and yes it is creating the eml or Msg file but I can't open that in MS outlook :( Need your help in doing that.

Comment: .EML file should open in Outlook, but if you cannot, try renaming the file extension to .MHT, then open it in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Saille - is it possible to save without a "from" address, so it can be sent from the user that opens it? Cheers.

Comment: You'd have to try it. I imagine your mail client would want to set the reply-to address according to its settings.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **Mailkit**. Just write below code

```
string fileName = "your filename full path";
MimeKit.MimeMessage message = CreateMyMessage ();
message.WriteTo(fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of community I came up with an solution for **.NET 5**. I have combined  [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-System-Net-Mail-MailM) old solution with suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595440/getting-system-net-mail-mailmessage-as-a-memorystream-in-net-4-5-beta) post and got inspired by **Mailkit** which resulted in nice extension method without unnecessary dependencies

```
public static class MailMessageHelper
{
    public static void WriteTo(this MailMessage mail, Stream stream)
    {
        Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        Type _mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

        // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
        ConstructorInfo _mailWriterConstructor =
            _mailWriterType.GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new Type[] { typeof(Stream), typeof(bool) },
                null);

        // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
        object _mailWriter =
          _mailWriterConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream, true });

        // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
        MethodInfo _sendMethod =
            typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod(
                "Send",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Call method passing in MailWriter
        _sendMethod.Invoke(
            mail,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new object[] { _mailWriter, true, true },
            null);

        // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
        MethodInfo _closeMethod =
            _mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod(
                "Close",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Call close method
        _closeMethod.Invoke(
            _mailWriter,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            Array.Empty<object>(),
            null);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
MailMessage mail = new(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailContent);
mail.WriteTo(new FileStream(@"path_to_file\new_mail.eml", FileMode.Create));
```

Also if you are using `MemoryStream` and want to get result in `string`, just change the return type of the extension method and at the end write

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

Enjoy

Comment: I can confirm that this works great in .net 5, thanks!

Comment: also works in .NET 6 and 7, thanks!

Comment: I'd be wary of using non public methods like this, they're non-public for a reason

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another the client.send failed (right after an actual send using that method) so I plugged in good 'ole CDO and ADODB stream. I also had to load CDO.message with a template.eml before setting the .Message values. But it works.

Since the above one is C here is one for VB

```
    MyMessage.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(mEmailAddress)
    MyMessage.To.Add(mToAddress)
    MyMessage.Subject = mSubject
    MyMessage.Body = mBody

    Smtp.Host = "------"
    Smtp.Port = "2525"
    Smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(------)

    Smtp.Send(MyMessage)        ' Actual Send

    Dim oldCDO As CDO.Message
    oldCDO = MyLoadEmlFromFile("template.eml")  ' just put from, to, subject blank. leave first line blank
    oldCDO.To = mToAddress
    oldCDO.From = mEmailAddress
    oldCDO.Subject = mSubject
    oldCDO.TextBody = mBody
    oldCDO.HTMLBody = mBody
    oldCDO.GetStream.Flush()
    oldCDO.GetStream.SaveToFile(yourPath)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As the question is with the tag [tag:C#], answers in other languages are not helpful, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this

please use these 2 reference
( using MailBee;)
( using MailBee.Mime;)

```
    public static string load(string to,string from,string cc,string bcc,string subject,string body, List<string> reportList,string path, bool HtmlbodyType)
    {
        try
        {
            MailBee.Mime.MailMessage msg = new MailBee.Mime.MailMessage();
            msg.From.AsString = from;
            msg.Subject = subject;
            if (HtmlbodyType == true)
            {
                msg.BodyHtmlText = body;
            }
            else
            {
                msg.BodyPlainText = body;
            }
            
            string[] receptionEmail = to.Split(new string[] { ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] ccEmail = cc.Split(new string[] { ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] bccEmail = bcc.Split(new string[] { ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string message = "";
            foreach (string To in receptionEmail)
            {
                msg.To.Add(To);
            }
            foreach (string CC in ccEmail)
            {
                    msg.Cc.Add(CC);
            }
            foreach (string Bcc in bccEmail)
            {
                    msg.Bcc.Add(Bcc);

            }
                for (int x = 0; x < reportList.Count; x++)
                {
                    string fileName = reportList[x];
                    msg.Attachments.Add(fileName);
                }

                msg.SaveMessage(path);
                return "Success";
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

    }
```