# How to write email on disk instead of sending to real address in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

How to write email (.eml file) on disk instead of sending to real address in asp.net? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml or *.msg file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("somehost"))
{
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
    client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\somedirectory";
    client.Send(message);
}
```

or using the config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\somedirectory" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend using the configuration file approach over that of code. It is likely that during development you'll want to write the emails to disk, but in deployment you'll want to transform your mailSettings to use a real Smtp server.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) to put emails into a configured directory instead of sending them. To do this, you need to set the [`DeliveryMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.deliverymethod.aspx) to `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` and set the [`PickupDirectoryLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation.aspx):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\emails" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

When you send emails using the standard `SmtpClient`, they will now get saved to the specified directory instead of actually being sent.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you are using `SmtpClient` since that's fairly standard.

Write your own SMTP implementation (it's very easy) that writes the messages that are sent through it to disk instead of actually emailing them.

Then

```
// mailMessage is MailMessage
var client = new SmtpClient("address.of.your.smtp.implementation");
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Now your server will intercept this send request and write it to disk.