# Save and send a mail using System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I'm trying to send and save the send email using C# code. But i can't get this done. I can either save the mail, or send it. But i can't get both done.

This is what i have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.From = new MailAddress("test@mail.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com"));
    message.Subject = "Test Subject";
    message.Body = "This is a test message";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    // Setup SMTP settings
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "******");

    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = basicCredential;
    smtp.Send(message);

    // save
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\Temp";
    smtp.Send(message); 

    return View();
}
```

So first i try to send the email. That works. Then i'm trying to save the email to my HDD. But it never gets saved. It does work when i don't send out the email and try to save it to my HDD right away. But i need to do both.

Anyone any idea how i can get this done? I just simply need to log the send messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail messages in the pickup directory are automatically sent by a local SMTP server (if present), such as IIS. ([SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation.aspx))

If you want to save to file system, you need to set the `DeliveryMethod` to `SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory`:

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory; 
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\Temp"; 
client.Send(message);
```

See [How to save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml or *.msg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the property `DeliveryMethod` to `SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectorynot` to not send the email.

Just changing the `PickupDirectoryLocation` will not work, because the property is not used when `DeliveryMethod` is set to `Network` (which is the default value).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.deliverymethod.aspx).