# How Do I save my composed email content as (.eml) before sending in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, eml

I am using the sample code below in sending emails. 
How can i save it first as an eml file before sending it as email in vb.net

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.exampledomain.com", 25) 
Dim mails As New MailMessage("user@exmple.com", "someuser", "TEST EMAIL", "Sample Message")    
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(user@exmple.com, "password")
SmtpServer.Send(mails)
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thank you.!

Answer (score 1):

To the person who have advised me on this thread to use this approach sorry if I did not fully Understand.. Appreciated your efforts!

This code solves my current issue with vb.net email.

> SmtpClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("login@sample", "user@123") 
>   SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory
>   SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Local Settings\Temp\FOLDER\" 
>   SmtpClient.Send(mails)
>   SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
>   SmtpClient.Send(mails) 
>   SmtpClient.Dispose()

Answer (score 0):

"*.EML" is a Microsoft Mail Format (Outlook, Outlook express) and some other clients can open/save it. You have to convert your email manually to such a format and store it on disk - .net does not provide any methods to convert you MailMessage to such a file. i don't think this is an easy task. I think you got something wrong.

Alternatively you can access outlook via MAPI - Than the Mapi-MailItem supports a Save-Method to store this mail on disk.

EDIT: Someone did this: look here: [stackoverflow 1264672](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file)

Comment: Noted Sir. My last resort would be adding BCC field to my email setup. Thank you sir!