# Can not get Item Attachment using Office 365 REST API

Tags: api, rest, outlook, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm using Office 365 REST API to get mail's attachments. I can get File Attachments normaly, but if the attachment has type : `"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment"`. I get this ItemAttachment's ID, then use this request to get File Attachment:
`https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/MESSAGE_ID/attachments/FILE_ITEM_ID?$expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment/Item`

Response return has new attribute "Item", contains a "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message" with HasAttachments = false. But try using the Web Outlook version, I can get this Item Attachment (In this case is a `.eml` file, exec it will open a new mail form).
Here is a example :

```js
{"@odata.context"=>
  "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAA%3D')/Attachments/$entity",
 "@odata.type"=>"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment",
 "@odata.id"=>
  "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/Users('framgia@en-japan.com')/Messages('AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAA=')/Attachments('AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAABEgAQAC0OcoIdL8lNgC520X2uWrg=')",
 "Id"=>"AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAABEgAQAC0OcoIdL8lNgC520X2uWrg=",
 "DateTimeLastModified"=>"2016-02-20T08:49:48Z",
 "Name"=>"[nhung]  mail  dùng chung cho company",
 "ContentType"=>"message/rfc822",
 "Size"=>18619,
 "IsInline"=>false,
 "Item@odata.context"=>
  "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAA%3D')/Attachments('AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgBGAAAAAADkAZdAt2CKRb7qeDvUo2cCBwAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAAAAAAEMAAAM_24JjVmvQpKtlDshSR9tAADa_spkAAABEgAQAC0OcoIdL8lNgC520X2uWrg%3D')/Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment/Item/$entity",
 "Item"=>
  {"@odata.type"=>"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message",
   "Id"=>nil,
   "DateTimeCreated"=>"2016-02-20T08:49:48Z",
   "DateTimeLastModified"=>"2016-02-20T08:49:48Z",
   "DateTimeReceived"=>"2016-02-20T08:49:42Z",
   "DateTimeSent"=>"2016-02-20T08:49:39Z",
   "HasAttachments"=>false,
   "Subject"=>"[nhung]  mail  dùng chung cho company",
   "Body"=>
    {"ContentType"=>"HTML",
     "Content"=>
      "<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<p>--&nbsp;cand_rep</p>\r\n<p>相川 真里和 --comp_name</p>\r\n<p>---&nbsp;comp_established</p>\r\n<p>---&nbsp;comp_address</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;--&nbsp;comp_business</p>\r\n<p>2110036 --&nbsp;comp_employee</p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"},
   "Sender"=>{"EmailAddress"=>{"Name"=>"framgia　個別アカウント01", "Address"=>"framgia@en-japan.com"}},
   "From"=>{"EmailAddress"=>{"Name"=>"framgia　個別アカウント01", "Address"=>"framgia@en-japan.com"}},
   "ToRecipients"=>[{"EmailAddress"=>{"Name"=>"framgia　個別アカウント01", "Address"=>"framgia@en-japan.com"}}],
   "ConversationId"=>"AAQkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgAQAAjK6iM-EvcpiBrx4E7Ogl4=",
   "IsReadReceiptRequested"=>false,
   "IsRead"=>true,
   "IsDraft"=>false,
   "WebLink"=>"https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkAGRiMjE2MTk3LTg3ZWUtNDg5ZC04YTMwLWYzNmU1MGY0Y2VlNgAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem"}}
```

So, how to get this `.eml` file by using Office 365 REST API?
Could someone can help me ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The Office 365 apis will not serve your item attachment as an *.eml file. If you need the *ItemAttachment* as an *.eml file you will have to build it yourself. Here are the steps: you do have access to all the information to this mail (see the new *Item* entry) so you can create *MailMessage* instance then, call one the technique proposed here to save a *MailMessage* to an *.eml file [How to save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml or *.msg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file)

Note: you did not mentioned the technical stack you use to request the Office365 apis, I assumed it is C#.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. I just want to say I can get a file if using Web version (in case is .eml file). I know my English is bad, sorry :) .

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "using web version"? Do you mean the .eml file is available when you select this mail with Outlook Web Access?

Comment: I mean access my mail box using outlook.office365.com web.