# How to save MailMesage to .msg file?

Tags: c#, outlook, mailmessage, msg, eml

I need save a MailMessage to .msg file. In this article have a solution but when I save as .msg file, it does not work in MS Outlook. It only great work when I save as.eml file.
[How to save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml or *.msg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file#_=_)

Note that I get when open the .msg file:

**Cannot open file: *path*. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click Properties check your permisstions for the folder.**

Thank all.

Comment: Where did you save the file? Is it the C: drive? Did you have a chance to check out permissions as was described in the error message?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I save to D:, but that is no problem. I can use and send those files created by my app. I just have a problem with show Vietnamese characters in subject mail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly are you creating the MSG file? It is completely different from an EML file - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229591/difference-between-a-msg-file-and-a-eml-file/16230261#16230261

MSG file format is a binary `IStorage` file, and its format is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx). You can parse your EML (MIME) file and copy one property at a time to a programmatically created MSG file.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) is an option (I am its author), you can use [Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) to create a new MSG file and [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import` method to import your existing EML file.

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set Msg = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\test.msg")
  Msg.Sent = true '//since Import does not copy this property
  Msg.Import("c:\temp\test.eml", 1024) ' //1024 is olRfc822
  Msg.Save
```

Comment: I don't use Redemption and I don't want to use 3rd-party tools. If you have another solution, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to use any third party products, you will need to handle MSG file creation and MIME file parsing explicitly in your code. Which can be challenging.

Comment: It means impossible without using 3rd party software? I hope you will see my article and if I looking forward to receiving your help. Thank you for your interest. [How to show Vietnamese characters in subjects mail .msg file Outlook (saved by C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451220/how-to-show-vietnamese-characters-in-subjects-mail-msg-file-outlook-saved-by-c)

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Convert an EML file to MSG?

Comment: Convert an EML file to MSG, that can a solution. I want to use MailMessage because it can Encoding Subject. I need to show Vietnamese characters in subject as mentioned in article [How to show Vietnamese characters in subjects mail .msg file Outlook (saved by C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451220/how-to-show-vietnamese-characters-in-subjects-mail-msg-file-outlook-saved-by-c)

Comment: So you are dealing with EML just to be able to set the Unicode characters? This doesn't make much sense to me..

Comment: Sorry for the disrespectful, I'm just trying to find a solution for my issue. And I need to try it with difference ways. Apologize if this is to offend you and thank you for your interest.

Comment: No offence at all, I am just trying to understand what you are trying to do and why.

Answer (score 4):

In Interop Outlook, this is how to locally save a mail as .msg.

```
mailItem.SaveAs(@"c:\path\to\save\mail.msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```