# How to show Vietnamese characters in subjects mail .msg file Outlook (saved by C#)?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, msg, mailitem

I am using this code to save a object Outlook.MailItem to .msg file.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem email = app.CreateItemFromTemplate(pathMail, Type.Missing);
email.To = "temp@gmail.com"
email.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
email.Body = txtBody.Text;
email.SaveAs(pathSave, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

It is great working, but it have a bug. If I write Vietnamese in txtSubject, the subject in .msg file will show "?" for Vietnamese characters.

Example: "Kiểm tra font tiếng Việt" --> "Ki?m tra font ti?ng Vi?t"

In body of .msg file, Vietnamese characters still show correctly ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTNcr.png)
)
And when I open .msg file by Notepad, I see Encoding follow:

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use olMsgUnicode format instead of olMsg.

Comment: Sorry, can you guide more specific? I just started using it recently. Thank you.

Comment: In your code above you have olMsg enum. You need to use olMsgUnicode.